# Flutter: A value of type 'GameNameEnum' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'GameNameEnum'

Tags: flutter, dart, types, widget

I am getting a really strange error in my code. When I try to use _dialogPlatform = newValue; or _dialogGameName = newValue; I get a red highlight by VS code saying I cannot assign a value with some type to a variable of the same type.
Complete error: A value of type 'Platform' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Platform'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Platform'.
Please help.

```
import 'package:all_gta_cheats/enums/enums.dart';
import 'package:all_gta_cheats/widgets/drop_down_menu.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FilterDialogBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const FilterDialogBox({
    Key? key,
    required this.initialPlatformValue,
    required this.initialGameNameValue,
    required this.initialIsFavValue,
    required this.onApply,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Platform initialPlatformValue;
  final GameNameEnum initialGameNameValue;
  final bool initialIsFavValue;
  final Function(
    Platform platform,
    GameNameEnum gameNameEnum,
    bool isFav,
  ) onApply;

  @override
  _FilterDialogBoxState createState() => _FilterDialogBoxState();
}

class _FilterDialogBoxState extends State<FilterDialogBox> {
  final TextStyle actionsTextStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 18);

  late GameNameEnum _dialogGameName;
  late Platform _dialogPlatform;
  late bool _dialogIsFav;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dialogGameName = widget.initialGameNameValue;
    _dialogPlatform = widget.initialPlatformValue;
    _dialogIsFav = widget.initialIsFavValue;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Search Filter'),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ListBody(
          children: <Widget>[
            DropDownMenu<Platform>(
              initialValue: _dialogPlatform,
              itemsList: Platform.values,
              onChanged: <Platform>(newValue) {
                //Platform value changes here
                _dialogPlatform = newValue;
                print(newValue.toString());
              },
            ),
            DropDownMenu<GameNameEnum>(
              initialValue: _dialogGameName,
              itemsList: GameNameEnum.values,
              onChanged: <GameNameEnum>(newValue) {
                //GameName value changes here
                _dialogGameName = newValue;
                print(newValue.toString());
              },
            ),
            SwitchListTile(
              title: const Text('Show only favourites'),
              value: _dialogIsFav,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  _dialogIsFav = value;
                  print(_dialogIsFav);
                  //widget.dialogIsFav = value;
                });
              },
              secondary: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          child: Text(
            'Cancel',
            style: actionsTextStyle,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text(
            'Apply',
            style: actionsTextStyle,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            widget.onApply(_dialogPlatform, _dialogGameName, _dialogIsFav);
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check the import that you have added from the correct file and it is not conflicting.

Comment: yes, they are correct I have checked. It is happening because of use of generic types may be